# What does the ^ character do in logical operation

Tags: python, if-statement, return, logic, operators

I'm practicing code on codingbat and came across this logic question:

> Given a number n, return True if n is in the range 1..10, inclusive. Unless outside_mode is True, in which case return True if the number is less or equal to 1, or greater or equal to 10.

The solution is:

```
if n == 1 or n == 10:
    return True
  return (n in range(1,11)) ^ outside_mode
```

If one googles "python ^ symbol" or "what does the ^ symbol do python" Google returns answers regarding the "@" symbol and the modulo symbol. It is not easy to find what this symbol does. This question should therefor be reopened to provide better chances of an early-stage programmer finding these answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` is the [bitwise exclusive or](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) (or XOR)

```
>>> True ^ True
False

>>> True ^ False
True

>>> False ^ True
True

>>> False ^ False
False
```

Answer (score 2):

It's bit-wise XOR. In Python, `True == 1`, and `False == 0`, so you can use bitwise operators to get the equivalent boolean operation.

For a single bit, `^` is the same as `!=`, so this is essentially the same as

```
return (n in range(1, 11) != outside_mode
```